# Experimental particle physics event shapes - why do different products have different event shapes?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, large-hadron-collider, particle-accelerators

Consider two interactions: $ \mu^+ \mu^- \rightarrow d \bar{d} $ and $ \mu^+ \mu^- \rightarrow gg $. The thrust of the down quarks will be different to the thrust of the gluon pair - why is this? More generally, why do different products have different values for other event shapes such as sphericity and planarity? I understand thrust mathematically and that it is essentially a measure of the coherence of the products (i.e. "jettiness"), but don't understand why certain products would be more "jetty", i.e. what property of the down quarks would give them a higher thrust than the gluons? Why might the gluons be more planar than the quarks or why might the quarks exhibit a greater sphericity?

Also a source where I can read more about different event shapes, what they mean and their significance would be welcome as there doesn't seem to be a great amount of information on the internet around this compared to other areas of physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gluons and quarks have many different properties: for instance, they have different masses, different spins, different (color) charges, and gluons are self-interacting. These combine in some complicated way to give complicated properties like "jettiness."

This may seem like an unsatisfying answer to you, and you are correct. But the only reason we use heuristic properties like jettiness in the first place is that quarks and gluons, as strongly-interacting particles, are too difficult to fully simulate the behavior of from first principles.

For learning more about event shapes, your best bet would probably be to read through talks and papers from the collider you are interested in. A lot of this can be rather collider-specific so there aren't really many general books on the topic or anything like that. Their significance is largely "this is some random combination of physical variables that happens to be helpful in identifying particles."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is what you say generally true for all event shapes, such as sphericity and planarity - that they are properties which when observed provide us with information about the interaction products? Or are other properties generally explainable by the properties of the products? Lastly, I am trying to simulate interactions and histogram these event shapes so there is not one collider which I am interested in, thus are there any particularly descriptive talks/papers that you have come across explaining what these different event shapes actually mean? Again thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Liam I have not seen any such talks or papers. The people using these properties are, by and large, not interested in what they "really mean," largely because they don't really mean anything. They are useful for doing physics, but they aren't really interesting in and of themselves. If you are interested in simulating these, you need to settle on a detector geometry first, since they all depend on the geometry. To start with a "jet" is not a real thing in physics, it's a specific way to group real things that occur in your detector, and defining one is different for every detector.

Comment: To support the complexity of the problem here is a paper from a CERN experiment, that fits experimental distributions from the data to quarks  and gluons https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1178 and the figures here http://cds.cern.ch/record/1471914/plots?ln=en